# Double "remove" icon on Favorite & Ignored tags

Tags: bug, tag-watching, ignored-tags

This is actually a really non-breaking, minor issue, but just for the sake of being documented.

So, if you don't have favorite tags, you'll be represented with "Add a favorite tag" link. This link does a similar thing to what "edit" link does: presenting a textbox to input a tag. Except, it doesn't hide "edit" link... which I then clicked out of curiosity, and voila!

> [image: double icon!]

Steps to reproduce:

1. (prerequisite) Remove all favorite tags
2. Click "Add a favorite tag"
3. Input a tag and click "Add" (now there is one tag which can be removed by clicking the icon, don't remove it though)
4. Click "edit"
5. Now you have 2 icons

Exiting the edit-mode solves this bug though, since you cannot access "Add a favorite tag" again. (Same thing happens with ignored tags)

- OS: Windows XP SP3
- Browser: Firefox 34.0

Comment: I can reproduce this. Must be a missing js call.